# Get data from external antenna connected via usb

Tags: java, android, receiver

I have to receive data from antenna connected to device via usb.
I tried to find some example but unfortunately i can not find any.
Can you guys give me some advice how to access data from it?

Thing is that, the antenna receive data from other device (nothing to consider there), and send it to me by blocks of data. Is there any thing that will give me access to it?

The antenna is not recognized via android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED receiver (same as eg. mouse).

Any advice will be appreciated.

Downvotes without any comment? Thanks guys.

**UPDATE**

I tried to get it by this code:

```
UsbManager mManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mManager.getDeviceList();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
```

With manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
```

But the list is empty (it works for eg. mouse, but not for antenna).

**UPDATE**

I find out that its possible that my device is blacklisted by UsbManager

```
private boolean isBlackListed(int clazz, int subClass, int protocol) {
    // blacklist hubs
    if (clazz == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HUB) return true;
    // blacklist HID boot devices (mouse and keyboard)
    if (clazz == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HID &&
            subClass == UsbConstants.USB_INTERFACE_SUBCLASS_BOOT) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any idea how to ignore it?

Comment: Just simple point to start will be great. I tried to get connected antenna device by usb host and INPUT_SERVICE, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hello in this repository you can find how to recognize your antenna conneted via usb.

Important: This project just recognize the antenna connected via usb, don't read data from the antenna.

I hope this can help you

https://github.com/tonybarajas/dvb_proof.git

Comment: Thanks for response, but unfortunately it does not find the antenna. Is there any other way to access it?

Comment: Ikazuchi, for this moment this is the only way I have found